# Change content-encoding to gzip for all files in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I have moved the static content of my web application to s3. All the files deployed are compressed using gzip. Now I want to make all these files public and inside metadata want to add 'Content-Encoding' to 'gzip'. Is it possible in any way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Amazon S3 Cache-Control for all bucket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385757/amazon-s3-cache-control-for-all-bucket)

Answer (score 0):

Objects in Amazon S3 can be made public via a Bucket Policy.

See: [Bucket Policy Examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

However, metadata is stored on each object individually and would need to be updated individually.

See: [How to change metadata on an object in Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754383/how-to-change-metadata-on-an-object-in-amazon-s3)

Or, use a utility such as BucketExplorer: [How to Update Amazon S3 Metadata in Batch](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-update-amazon-s3-metadata-in-batch.html)