# Is there a way I can add DEFAULT cache control to a bucket in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I saw this post:

[how to add cache control in AWS S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501465/how-to-add-cache-control-in-aws-s3)

It tells me how I can modify the cache control after loading in objects. But is there a way that I can give the objects loaded into my bucket **default** cache control TTL ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Amazon S3 Cache-Control for all bucket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385757/amazon-s3-cache-control-for-all-bucket)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Cache Control is a per object meta data.  There is no default value for it at bucket level.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUT.html