# Setting metadata on default Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to set a default cache-control:no cache to the complete bucket. I know I can do this by setting meta-data.
But when I check the properties of the bucket, I don't see any metadata to set. How can I enable this?[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon S3 Cache-Control for all bucket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385757/amazon-s3-cache-control-for-all-bucket)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metadata is not applied to a bucket. It's applied to an object. S3 doesn't have a feature that would automatically apply metadata to a newly created object.

Third party products like Cloudberry Explorer and Bucket Explorer allow setting default metadata for a bucket, but they apply this metadata to all the objects in the background.

Comment: Mind you that depending on how smart your 3rd party solution is to maintain certain metadata on all your objects, you might incur charges that are for COPY requests for your entire bucket's contents.